# user id not working on page

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm retrieving a user id from a database and saved it in a variable inside a foreach loop and want to use that user id on the same page inside another div.But the problem is, that variable isn't working on that page and giving this error "Undefined variable Id".Please guide me how to do this in a right way.Thank you!

Here is my PHP code of calling that user id from database:

```
<?php        
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];            
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '$email' ";
$result = $obj->run_query($query);            
foreach ($result as $key) {                         
$id = $key['Id'];
}                       
?>
```

And here is my Html where I'm calling that variable:

```
<?php    
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_reservation WHERE user_id = '$id'";
$result = $obj->run_query($query);    
$count = 1;    
foreach ($result as $key) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $count++;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key['book_title'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key['book_author'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key['reserve_date'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key['return_date'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to fetch the query to get the results.

Comment: what is `run_query`, I am not popular about it.

Comment: Where? and how to do that? please show me @C0dekid.php

Comment: run_query is a user-defined function of my own. @FrayneKonok

Comment: @AishaSalman You are using a different mysql/mysqli or user defined class, but maybe it's something like `$result->fetch()` or something. But that depends on what class you are using or if this function even exists.

Comment: ok, I got it. Thanks :) @C0dekid.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set the var $id. So it does not exist yet. Define it before the foreach like so:

```
<?php        
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];            
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '$email' ";
$id = '';
$result = $obj->run_query($query);            
foreach ($result as $key) {                         
$id = $key['Id'];
}                       
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) @Refilon

Comment: @AishaSalman, no problem, glad I could help. Please accept my answer when you can.

Comment: without fetching the resource how can get the data from database?

Comment: @FrayneKonok, Maybe it's an selfmade object. And it return the result already :)

Comment: I'm already fetching  resource from database by using foreach loop inside a table @FrayneKonok

Comment: she did't mention it while i am asking her what is `run_query()`?? Okey, She got the success, that's it.